# Get-ADUser CSV file disabled true and false filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

The script below works as is, I need to add the `enabled -eq $true` piece so I can audit the user list to see if they are also enabled (not just disabled). I have tried various ways and the scripted error out. Can anyone help?

```
$userID = Import-Csv "c:\users.csv"

foreach ($user in $userID) {
    $employeeID = $user.employeeID
    Get-ADUser -Filter {employeeID -eq $employeeID -and Enabled -eq $false} -Properties displayName,employeeID,mail,intelOwnerID,title,"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed","lastLogon" |
        select "Displayname", "Enabled",
            @{n="PasswordExpiryDate";e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}},
            @{n='LastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogon)}},
            SamAccountName, employeeID, mail, intelOwnerID, title |
        Export-Csv -Append "c:\temp\usersacct.csv"
```

Comment: What are you talking about? AD users can't be enabled *and* disabled at the same time. Or do you mean you want to enumerate both enabled and disabled accounts? In that case simply remove the condition from the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get both enabled and disabled users that are listed in your .csv you just need to stop filtering on     `Enabled -eq $false`.  Just change this line:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {employeeID -eq $employeeID -and Enabled -eq $false} -Properties displayName,employeeID,mail,intelOwnerID,title,"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed","lastLogon" |
```

to

```
 Get-ADUser -Filter {employeeID -eq $employeeID} -Properties displayName,employeeID,mail,intelOwnerID,title,"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed","lastLogon" |
```